# How to Boot CentOS in CLI?

Tags: linux, command-line, boot, centos-6

I have a CentOS 6.2 OS which boots into GUI.  How, upon startup, can I *not* boot into the GUI and instead, boot into the CLI? I want to do this at computer startup time.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When you are at the GRUB menu where you select which OS to boot (if this menu don’t appear, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> while you get the “Booting CentOS in X seconds”), press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit your boot commands. You should see a screen like this: (parameters may vary)

[image: GRUB menu]

Look for the line that begins with `kernel`. Choose it and then press <kbd>e</kbd> again. You will be at a simple editor, add `3` to the end of this line. This means booting in runlevel 3, which is text-mode only.

To make this stick: edit `/etc/inittab` and look for a line that begin with `id:5`. Replace the `5` in that line by `3`. You can find a brief description of runlevels [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_RHEL_6_Runlevels_and_Services#Configuring_the_Default_RHEL_6_Runlevel), but shortly:

- **Runlevel 0 and 6:** halt and reboot the machine, respectively.
- **Runlevel 1:** No services running, only root can login.
- **Runlevel 2:** Users can login but no networking.
- **Runlevel 3:** Networking and text-mode.
- **Runlevel 4:** unused.
- **Runlevel 5:** GUI.

Comment: After making the kernel edit for the runlevel boot mode, (and pushing `b` for "boot"), is it still supposed to load the splash screen?

Comment: @BGM I think so, but it should drop you to the login prompt after it finishes.

Comment: It works for level 1, but not for level 3.  Is that strange?

Comment: Anyway, Renan has the answer.  I also found it here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/auditd-fails-to-start-on-boot-846100/

Comment: Thanks it's fine for 6.4. I don't think this works for CentOS 7 though...

Comment: @lppier I haven't used CentOS 7 much, but likely it doesn't work since CentOS now uses systemd.

Comment: For CentOS 7, type this into the Terminal:
'systemctl set-default multi-user.target' and to change it back, 'systemctl set-default graphical.target'

Comment: @Renan In statement "add 3 to the end of this line"  What "this line" refers too?

Answer (score 4):

1. Apart from what Renan mentioned, you can switch to another runlevel by simply executing `sudo init [level-number]` -- this is temporary, when you reboot, you get to your default, configured in `/etc/inittab`.
2. If you don't want to see splash screen, you need to replace kernel param `rhgb` with `text` in boot menu. To make it permanent, edit `/boot/grub/grub.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

In Centos 8, you have to use `systemctl set-default TARGET.target` command and replace `TARGET` with either `multi-user` for runlevel of 3, i.e. Terminal, or `graphical` for runlevel of 5.

So this is the command to use in Centos 8 to switch to Terminal when the system gets restarted:
`systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Once in Terminal, you can start the GUI again if you need to by using:
`systemctl isolate graphical`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how /inittab/etc looks on Centos - run:
`systemctl set-default multi-user.target`
and reboot to get to the CLI.

```
# inittab is no longer used.
#
# ADDING CONFIGURATION HERE WILL HAVE NO EFFECT ON YOUR SYSTEM.
#
# Ctrl-Alt-Delete is handled by /usr/lib/systemd/system/ctrl-alt-del.target
#
# systemd uses 'targets' instead of runlevels. By default, there are two main targets:

# multi-user.target: analogous to runlevel 3
# graphical.target: analogous to runlevel 5
#
# To view current default target, run:
# systemctl get-default
#
# To set a default target, run:
# systemctl set-default TARGET.target
```